# Track Friend Location android like GPS Tracking Pro

Tags: android, gps

I want to make an application that will track the location of my friends,relatives etc.Basically In my application when the user enters his friend phone number,I want to track friend location from friend phone GPS or wifi or cell tower.I want the similar functionality like GPS Tracking Pro "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsp.android.c&hl=en"

I got one solution but for that my friend should also installed this application and should continuously update its location,But I don't want my friend to install this application to update its location and should update any location updates.Can anyone please help me that how can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, what you want is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. There does not exist a public Web service where anonymous cowards can provide a phone number and get the location of that phone, for arbitrary phones.

Comment: but the Application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsp.android.c&hl=en gives the location.If its not possible then how this application provides?

Comment: @user2779069: They have reached agreements to use private location APIs from AT&T, Verizon, TMobile, and Sprint.